# Creating a 2D array with specific length and width

Tags: javascript, arrays

*see the title. I basically need it to create a blank array that can be any dimension like 40x60. Basically maybe something like `makeArray(3, 4)` makes an array like:

```
[][][]
[][][]
[][][]
[][][]
```

Comment: JavaScript arrays are not fixed-size, so you can usually get away with not preallocating them. [What have _you_ tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @MattBall I have seen questions like this but it's usually for a making a square array not a specified X and Y dimension.

Comment: That's pretty much irrelevant. "Square array" is just the special case of rows == columns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Javascript arrays are dynamic in size.  However, if you wish to create an array of a specific size, the `Array` constructor takes an optional length argument:

```
function makeArray(d1, d2) {
    var arr = new Array(d1), i, l;
    for(i = 0, l = d2; i < l; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(d1);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Slightly shorter:

```
function makeArray(d1, d2) {
    var arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < d2; i++) {
        arr.push(new Array(d1));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
function makeArray(w, h, val) {
    var arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Is "d1" for x length and "d2" for y length?

Comment: Yes.  `d1` is the `width` of the array, and `d2` is the `height` of the array (if that makes sense).  If you use that, you can use `makeArray(3, 4);` (as per your original question).

Comment: Is there a way to fill each cell with a default value?

Comment: @lawm Look at my updated answer.

Comment: So like this? makeArray(3, 4, "a");

Comment: @lawm Correct.  That will create a 3X4 array with each value defaulting to a.

Answer (score 3):

Well make Array would be a simple function like this

```
    ​function makeArray(a,b) {
        var arr = new Array(a)
        for(var i = 0;i<a;i++)
            arr[i] = new Array(b)
        return arr
    }
    console.log(makeArray(4,4))
```

​
But you don't have to define Arrays with functions you can simply 
do something like

```
var arr=[]
arr[10] = 10
```

Which would result in a Array with 10 Elements, 0 - 9 are `undefined`

But thats enough of an Answer in this case, i tried to point some things out in this question regarding Arrays, if you're interested you can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13725353/1487756)